# Are the entropy values calculated with average heat capacities

Tags: organic-chemistry

I asked myself whether the entropy values in an ordinary table in thermochemistry are calculated with exact specific heat capacities for each little temperature change or if they are averaged the capacities and assumed to be constant.

Comment: Which ordinary table in thermochemistry? Each source should cite the origin of the data and, if it is a primary source (the one that computed the entropies in the first place, not one duplicating the values) then provide a description of the computations involved.

Comment: This one https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/standard-enthalpy-formation-value-Gibbs-free-energy-entropy-heat-capacity-organic-d_1979.html

There stands "internationally agreed values".

Comment: Not sure where that site gets its data, might be from CRC or NIST. For the later, you may start looking in https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/thermo/